# how to match `“` with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

There is a symbol in tweets : `“`

> “@BrownieSWP: High is s***????” you like 12 tf

The symbol is not `"`. I write this regex to match it:

```
re.sub('(“|”)', '"', tweet)
```

This regex `(“|”)` worked in sublime text. But it didn't work in python.

Comment: Please try to refrain from using expletives even in your examples.

Comment: Seems to work in python too http://regex101.com/r/tJ3rD4/1. Have you tried what Code Generator suggests?

Comment: The parentheses in your regex are superfluous.  When matching a single character, it is often considered more elegant to use a character class, although it's actually one character more in this case.

Comment: @KronoS Sorry, It's example from tweets. I will mind it next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character you have copy/pasted is a [U+201C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) "LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK". In the `re.sub()` you also have the corresponding right quotation mark [U+201D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm). Perhaps the environment in which you tried to paste it wasn't set up to handle Unicode correctly, and converted it to some other encoding. (See also [How do I see the current encoding of a file in Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195871/how-do-i-see-the-current-encoding-of-a-file-in-sublime-text-2))

You can always use Python's escape codes to unambiguously and ASCII-compatibly refer to a Unicode character; `re.sub(u'[\u201c\u201d]', '', tweet)`

Comment: This is the method I prefer if there's ever a situation where Unicode character support in editors may be questioned.  From annoying previous experience, it only took one misconfigured editor to screw up an entire source file.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me,

```
>>> s = r"“@BrownieSWP: High is s***????” you like 12 tf"
>>> m = re.sub(r'[”“]', r'', s)
>>> m
'@BrownieSWP: High is s***???? you like 12 tf'
```