# Symfony3 Error encoding utf-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sublimetext3, symfony

### I need to use the utf-8 for my site with symfony.

My head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Awesome title </title>
</head>
```

I want to show this text:
`<h2 class="center">Veuillez vous connecter pour accéder au CRM.</h2>`

But I get:

> Veuillez vous connecter pour acc�der au CRM.

I read that it may be due to sublime text way to save the file, but sublime does everything on utf-8.

---

I precise that I've done some research and that the problem is, I guess, not from the database.

---

### EDIT

From the answer of pooler, I checked in the console:

> view.encoding() ([How do I see the current encoding of a file in Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195871/how-do-i-see-the-current-encoding-of-a-file-in-sublime-text-2#16199148))

Then I saved the file in utf-8 with File->Save with Encoding->UTF-8.

My encoding was Western (Windows 1252)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your file must be saved in utf-8 encoding too